# How to add GoogleSignIn in AWS Amplify Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-signin, aws-amplify

I want to implement GoogleSignIn feature in my android application, but in the amazon amplify auth documentation there is no clear way to do it step by step.
I think there are there  ways to add GoogleSignIn in android application, 1. the AndroidClient SDK, 2. OAuth ( with WebView). 3. SignInUI

But i want to do it with GoogleSignIn SDK, currently i'm doing this steps, is it correct way to do google sign in with google android client ? :

- Implement GoogleSignIn SDK by myself
- Get Google token in select gmail account dialog
- Call federatedSignIn method with google token and get a amazon auth token

I get a token in result of federatedSignIn method and my amazon auth sdk global initialize callback state is changing to authenticated, but the token is not valid for backend, i think it's google raw token without any changes.

```
fun cognitoAuthWithGoogle(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {

        var idToken = account.idToken

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().federatedSignIn(IdentityProvider.GOOGLE.toString(), idToken, object : Callback<UserStateDetails> {
            override fun onResult(result: UserStateDetails?) {
                result.toString()
            }

            override fun onError(e: java.lang.Exception?) {
                e?.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
    }

    fun initGoogleSignIn() {
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()


        var mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        loginGoogleButton.setOnClickListener {
            val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 100)
        }


    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().handleAuthResponse(data)
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                account.toString()
                cognitoAuthWithGoogle(account!!)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```